# Content Deployment and what happens when deployed files change on the remote server?

Tags: 2010, 2013, content-deployment

A quick and simple question which I can't find a definite answer on:

When using Content Deployment to e.g. **deploy a subweb** from <kbd>Farm A</kbd> to <kbd>Farm B</kbd>, <kbd>**Farm A**</kbd> is the "Master".

**What happens the next content deployment when somebody has changed a file in <kbd>Farm B</kbd> after the first deployment?**

I see a couple of possibilities:

1. The next deployment will just overwrite all files on Farm B
2. The next deployment will "merge" the files and will not copy over the files with a new ChangeToken
3. The next deployment will synchronize both farms and take the files with the newer ChangeToken for each farm

(I know case 3 is not correct, that's the whole reason products such as AvePoint Replicator exist)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to author any content in the target farm for a successful content deployment

A set of Best Practices and issues are compiled by Stefan Gossner [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/01/16/content-deployment-best-practices.aspx)

Comment: Not supposed to is fine, but I would like to know what happens.

Comment: One scenario which i have faced is the version of the page gets changed when you edit the page in target, So the source and target version will differ the target version will be higher in this case.So changes wont get reflected into target.